# How to convert generic type array to specialized type array in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I'm using firebase in my application. So, the snapshotChanges() method of firebase returning an Observable of type SnapshotAction array which I want to convert to specific type array after subscribing to an Observable. So, how can we do this in typescript?

**Have a look at codebase below to understand it better,**

```js
// Below observable is returned by firebase snapshotChanges() method 
Observable<SnapshotAction<Product>[]>

// Now, after I subscribe to the above observable I get below type,
SnapshotAction<Product>[]

// Now I want to convert "SnapshotAction<Product>[]" to "Product[]" in typescript
```

Comment: Rupesh, if you're happy with my answer please update/accept the answer so I can get some magic internet points.

Comment: Matt, I've given my feedback by clicking on the up arrow beside your answer. However, I can't see any option to accept it or update it.

Comment: Also, my feedback has been recorded by stack overflow but I need at least 15 points to cast my vote here which I believe I'll hopefully achieve asap.

Answer (score 0):

Snapshot action has a payload field which will give you a

```
DatabaseSnapshot<Product>
```

A DatabaseSnapshot has a val() method which will return a Product or null depending if the snapshot exists. So you can write a small function like this to extract the product:

```
function example(input: SnapshotAction<string>[]): (string | null)[] {
    return input.map(action => action.payload.val())
}
```

Note that this is return string | null because the snapshot might not exist. You could look at

```
action.payload.exists()
```

If you want to do additional checks or filtering.

Comment: Thanks @matt helliwell, your help in my query has really helped me achieve what I wanted to with my codebase. I iterated over each SnapshotAction<Product>[ ] array using a map( ) and extracted the Product json using the product.payload.val( ) method and pushed it in a Product[ ] array which was my end goal.

Answer (score 0):

So, I finally converted the **SnapshotAction< Product >[ ]** array to a more specific type **Product[ ]** by mapping each element of type **SnapshotAction< Product >** and extracting the payload(json) value from it of type **Product** and then pushing it into a Product[ ] which I declared right in the first line of my code below.

```js
products: Product[] = [];

this.productService.getAll().pipe(
      switchMap((products: SnapshotAction<Product>[]) => {
      
        // Our intention starts here
        products.map((product: SnapshotAction<Product>) => {
          let prod: Product = product.payload.val();
          prod.key = product.key;
          
          this.products.push(prod);
        });
        
      });
    );
```

```
Final Outcome: 
[
      {category: 'bread', imageUrl: 'img1_url.jpg', price: 3, title: 'Freshly Baked Bread', key: '-MrS7JBEldfwCbmGSCBY'},
      {category: 'fruits', imageUrl: 'img2_url.jpg', price: 234, title: 'Orange', key: '-MrSweHxR168xz3lyxm1'},
      {category: 'vegetables', imageUrl: 'img3_url.jpg', price: 2.22, title: 'Spinach', key: '-MrTBTEe4sXK3Hh31Fui'}
]
```

Comment: Maybe check how you can improve this answer a little bit with just not code but also an explanation, contexting, etc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: nilsandrey, I hope the answer is more clear now.